# How using with istringstream in c++?

Tags: c++, string, stream

I look for function to split whitespace in c++. i find this code on internet. i want to know what is says.

```
  string line;
  istringstream buf(line);
  istream_iterator<string> beg(buf), end;
  vector<string> tokens(beg, end);
  return tokens;
```

Comment: Be more specific; I believe there's tons of articles explaining it. SO is not a site to give you code interpretation.

Comment: why i need istringstream? i wanna split by whitespace

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate your exact purpose.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Please be clear and check you can find this in any other stack exchange websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<std::string> SplitByWhiteSpace(std::string stringToSplit)
{
    std::istringstream buf(stringToSplit);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> beg(buf), end;
    return std::vector<std::string>(beg, end);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens = SplitByWhiteSpace("Hello World!");

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<tokens[i]<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That code splits the string by white-space and returns all tokens in a vector. You can then print all the tokens in the vector.

It is almost the same as doing (same result, different technique):

```
std::vector<std::string> SplitByWhiteSpace(std::string stringToSplit)
{
    std::string word;
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::istringstream buf(stringToSplit);

    while (buf >> word)
    {
        tokens.push_back(word);
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: I try to understand where to split happen? when I write the std::vector<std::string>(beg, end); ??